# sscanf_s with double %c

Tags: c++, scanf

I have some problems with sscanf_s when I want to extract two chars.

Example Code:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <string.h>

int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv[])
{
   char* text = "ab";
   char a = ' ';
   char b = ' ';

   sscanf_s(text, "%c%c", &a, &b); //the same problem when I use %1c%1c

   return 0;
}
```

This doesn't work when I run it:

> Unhandled exception at 0x0F76D6AC (msvcr120d.dll) in
>   ConsoleApplication2.exe: 0xC0000005: Access violation writing location
>   0x00000000.

When I try it with two integers like `%i%i`, then everything is working.

Comment: `%c` of `sscan_f`need size parameter. E.g `sscanf_s(text, "%c%c", &a, 1,  &b, 1);` ref  [sscanf_f](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t6z7bya3.aspx)

Comment: **READ THE DOCUMENTATION**

Comment: Why do you `#include <iostream>` then just go ahead and `sscanf`?

Answer (score 5):

You need to specify size .

> [...] except that `%c`, `%s`, and `%[` conversion specifiers each expect two arguments (the usual pointer and a value of type rsize_t indicating the size of the receiving array, **which may be 1 when reading with a %c into a single char**.

For reference -http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf

So use `1` as size to read into single `char`

Re-write like this -

```
sscanf_s(text, "%c%c", &a,(rsize_t)1,&b,(rsize_t)1);
  //explicit casts as corrected in comments by chux
```

Comment: The size needs to be type `rsize_t`.  `1` is type `int`.

Comment: @chux Yes Sir I agree , but if you see the examples,it is stated at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/w40768et.aspx) as well as [here](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf) while taking input in single `char` the size could be `1` . It would have been a different case if that was an array .

Comment: The issue is not _value_.  1 is the correct _value_.  `1` is not the correct _type_.  Both the links provided do not use a naked `1`.  Those examples would imply `_countof(a)` and `(rsize_t) sizeof(a)` or simply `sscanf_s(text, "%c%c", &a,(rsize_t)1,&b,(rsize_t)1);`.

Comment: @chux  Sorry Sir , but I fail to see any explicit cast being used for `1` in examples in those links . _But thanks for the correction , I shall incorporate that_ :-)